# How to create a ASP.NET 4.0 Route based on DataBinded value?

Tags: asp.net, routes

I have ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms application. I use Routing for any of my links just to try new 4.0 feature.

My problem is that i have a ListView with Users Table, near each UserName i have edit anchor tag like so

```
<a href="<%$ RouteUrl:RouteName=userEditRoute %>">edit</a>
```

How do i combine both parameter which user i want to edit

```
<%# Eval("userID") %>
```

and put this value to

```
<%$ RouteUrl:RouteName=userEditRoute,userID=??? %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you can pass the route Values along, like:

```
<a href="<% #GetRouteUrl(userEditRoute, new with {.id=Eval("Id")})%>">edit</a>
```

Comment: Eval("someValue") required DataBinding tag <%# %>

Comment: I'm to used to Razor Views :) forgot that little details ... BTW, why webforms? Razor is soooo much simpler!

Comment: @balexandre, i don't feel confident enough to make MVC website at my job. I still miss some details and have no time to waste.

Comment: it's a breeze :) I was like you, but I started a really big project in MVC3 and I'm loving it, you will find plenty of questions about MV3 here from me but in a quick time I got all them answered and learned a lot with it. Start seeing the videos from PluralSight (for free) on the left column on this page: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Thanks, i have a paid account in there and finished all MVC 3.0 related videos. Even send thanks to Scott Allen who made these series for being clear enough but there only basic tutorials in there when i make pretty advanced stuff at my job... Maybe you right i should next time start MVC so my boss won't understand a bit of code at all. For now i just need quick tip on Routes without MVC.

Comment: But my question doesn't help at all? you can pass the id with `new with`